# Removing my Lenovo computer from the dock re-sizes my windows

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, docking-station

I am experiencing a strange problem that seems to be specific to the Lenovo that I and my work colleagues have. It is a W540 Thinkpad, and the issue is that when you undock the computer from a Lenovo dock, the windows all re-size to slightly smaller than the desktop. The windows all think they are maximized but you can click above the top which is super annoying.

I had a quick look for a solution but I cant seem to find any. Has anyone encountered this before or know of a solution?

[image]